# Adding new column in hive existing tale

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

My data is as shown below

TIME=2012111|evnt=XYA|SESN=ABC|SVNM=OKL
TIME=2012111|evnt=ABC|SVNM=MON
.
.
.
.
TIME=2012111|evnt=XYA|SESN=ABC

I have sesn only either at first line or at last line, I have to create new column which will hold this session id (i.e.SESN=ABC).

Any lead on this will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific with your Question.

Are you looking for `Alter table Add column?`

Comment: No that i know I want add new column and then populate it with session id (SESN=ABC), this is available only in first and last line.